# archive-{post_type}.php is defaulting to category.php vs. archive.php on category searches

Tags: custom-post-types

I am using `archive-{post_type}.php` for queries of a custom post type.  I want the system to use `archive.php` for category searches but it is defaulting to `category.php` which I am using for category searches (different categories) for regular posts.  Does anyone have an idea of what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by *category searches*?

In `is_category()` branch of [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) `category.php` precedes `archive.php`, it is intended and wanted behavior. If you want to change template behavior for specific category you will need to override that logic, likely in `template_redirect` hook or around that.

Comment: That is what I thought, too, until I found this in the Codex (this was wishful thinking on my part):    `http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy`.   You have to scroll down a bit to see the chart. I will research it and try your suggestion on the template_redirect.  Thank you!